# JPA, inheritance JOINED, multiple ID's

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a little JPA question.
Assume you have such tables: (structure is fixed)

```
PERSON
--
ID, 
DEPARTMENT_ID
```

...

```
SPECIALWORKER
------
ID, PERSON_ID, SPECIALDEPARTMENT_ID
```

...

```
DEPARTMENT
-------
ID,
```

...

```
SPECIALDEPARTMENT
-------
ID,
```

...

In Java I would build it with a simple hierarchy: `SpecialWorker extends Person` and `SpecialDepartment extends Department`. We will have "simple" Persons as well as "simple" Departments.

In JPA I try to build that scenario with a JOINED_Table inheritance, but I can't get it working. Any ideas?

*edit*

the coding, i hope i missed nothing.
I got a integrity exception when i try to insert a specialworker.
When i insert a specialworker jpa has to set the fk to departement (baseclass person) as well as the fk to the special departement (from the concrete current class)

```
 @Entity
  @Table(name = "DEPARTEMENT")
  @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
  public class Departement
  {
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    ...
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "SPECIALDEPARTEMENT")
  @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID_DEPARTEMENT", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  public class SpecialDepartement
    extends Departement
    implements Serializable
  {


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer                                                 id01;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "specialDepartement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<SpecialWorker> workers;

    ...

  }



  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PERSON")
  @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
  public class Person
  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Max(19)
    private Long                        id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DEPARTEMENT", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Departement departement;

    ...
  }



  @Entity
  @Table(name = "SWORKER")
  @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  public class SpecialWorker
    extends Person
  {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer                     id01;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SPECIALDEPARTEMENT", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private SpecialDepartement  specialdepartement;
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with what you tried even if it did not work?

Comment: coding updated aboce

Comment: Why do you need both keys `ID` and `PERSON_ID` in `SPECIALWORKER` table? Your schema looks like it needed `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy throwing away `PERSON_ID` column.

Comment: we have some columns in both table (user of change, user of creation etc.) it seems not allowed to repeat tha columns in SPECIALWORKER